# Frequent fatal error in Phalcon (dependency injector required for ORM)

Tags: php, phalcon

What is the source of following fatal error?, I have no clue about it and it occurred frequently:

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Exception' with message 'A dependency injector container is required to obtain the services related to the ORM' in [no active file]:0
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Phalcon\Mvc\Model-&gt;serialize()
#1 {main}
  thrown in <b>[no active file]</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
```

Phalcon 0.6

update:
my project is a bit modified version of  invo sample project. Currently I have its User model. I only modified ACL of INVO project. How can I log Phalcon stack trace a little more elaborated.

```
    $di->set('db', function() use ($config) {
        return new \Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql(array(
            "host" => $config->database->host,
            "username" => $config->database->username,
            "password" => $config->database->password,
            "dbname" => $config->database->name
        ));
    });
```

Because of MVC structure of my site I can not easily provide an example code that generate this error. When this error occurred in first page it will displayed in all subsequent pages.

Comment: Can you provide a code example on where this is failing or how you bootstrap your application and a model?

Answer (score 1):

Did you set a model manager and a metadata manager like so:

```
    // Set Models manager
    $this->_di->set(
        'modelsManager',
        function()
        {
            return new \Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Manager();
        }
    );

    // Set Models metadata
    $this->_di->set(
        'modelsMetadata',
        function()
        {
            return new \Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Metadata\Memory();
        }
    );
```

Comment: I had not set 'modelsManager', indeed it is not set in https://github.com/phalcon/invo/blob/master/public/index.php that I was used as a base for my new project. Even setting that did not solve the issue. The error message is displayed after html tag at the botton of all page and disappears when I log out from invo site.